# Get image from one page and show/add it on another page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

We had one custom wordpress requirement that when we are adding images (for instance, a car image) on the homepage, any time after that, when creating a new page, that car image should appear on the right hand side by default. Thus, whenever I'm changing the homepage car image to some other image it will reflect on other pages also.

I'm using divi [theme for reference](http://farnazfever.com). They are using a pagebuilder. We are adding the image in home page. I'm not using sidebar.

I have tried many plugins, but just unable implement this requirement.

Comment: you need to give more details, when you say right-hand side do you mean a sidebar? what is your html layout like? what you want should be easily done by custom coding in the PHP templates.

Comment: how it can be done please guide me. I have edited my question.

Comment: Sidebar.php sounds like it is exactly what you need to use, but I agree with @Reuben L., we need more information / code.

Answer (score -2):

You must delete the first, and then from the top delete add media button 
then choose your image as you like.